# Using the Clipboard API - Throws error "is not defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, clipboard

So as has been encountered/asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21854062/copy-to-clipboard-in-jquery-javascript-without-flash-for-ipad-iphone) I'm trying to make a copy function that works on non-flash devices.

This has led me to the [Clipboard API](http://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/).
But I can't seem to get it working properly, this is what I have so far:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on( 'click', '.copy-btn', function (e) {
        var data = 'This has been copied';

        var clip = new ClipboardEvent( 'copy' );
        clip.clipboardData.setData( 'text/plain', data );
        clip.preventDefault();

        e.target.dispatchEvent( clip );
    });
});
```

The code is quite self-explanatory, on a click of the button it should copy "This has been copied" to the clipboard. Upon trying to do so I get:
"Uncaught ReferenceError: ClipboardEvent is not defined". What am I missing? Shouldn't this be "built in" or is there a need to call the API in anyway?
Also stumbled upon [this](http://codepen.io/suhajdab/pen/wpulo) which gives the same error.

This seems to be a simple misstake, or is the API currently not working?

Comment: With which browser you're trying to do it?

Comment: I've tried with IE 10 and Chrome v34, but end goal is getting it to work on mobile browsers

Comment: @user3088863: Neither of those supports the `ClipboardEvent` constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To date, only Firefox supports the `ClipboardEvent` constructor; [support info](http://caniuse.com/#feat=clipboard).

Comment: Even better, iOS doesn't support the clipboard api _at all_.

Comment: @Cerbrus: According to caniuse (the link above), iOS Safari 5.0 and up have some level of support, just not the `ClipboardEvent` constructor.

Comment: Oh wait, that's Opera mini I was looking at, derp.

Comment: Oh, thought the partial support would include the copy functionallity as it seemed pretty basic. But now I see that android doesnt support it either so that's that idea in the bin ;) Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to use it without the constructor?