# For text input, how to make it so that clicking on it will select everything?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, input, vuejs2, jquery-events

I've found this: [Copy to Clipboard that also works on Mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015253/copy-to-clipboard-that-also-works-on-mobile)

But VueJS doesn't use jQuery. So what is the alternative to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can still use JQuery, just add the script to your HTML, but if you don't want to use JQuery the alternative is to use vanilla Javascript (pure JS).

The `setSelectionRange(start, end)` method of an input is the answer you may want.

Here's a demo.

[Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/s7L895n7/)

Answer (score 60):

Based on https://medium.com/vuejs-tips/tip-11-auto-select-input-text-on-focus-9eca645073cd article:

```
<input @focus="$event.target.select()">
```

Answer (score 13):

```
<input type="text" ref="input" @click="selectAll">

selectAll() {
  this.$refs.input.select();
}
```

[]: https://jsfiddle.net/s7L895n7/14/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: I would not use the `click ` event here, because you might also want this to work when the user for example switches to the input field by tabbing;