# copy text to clipboard using javascript for both mobile and desktop

Tags: javascript, html

I want text copied to the clipboard using JavaScript which works both in phone and desktop

I have the following code and it works only for desktop not for mobile

```
<input type="text" value="Hello World" id="myInput">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  /* Get the text field */
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");

  /* Select the text field */
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /* For mobile devices */

  /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
  
  /* Alert the copied text */
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Check is this can help you, https://stackoverflow.com/a/35615153/9676887

Comment: pretty sure this has been ask & answered many times, years ago... did you try searching?

Comment: The mobile browsers you are testing with do probably not support the Clipboard API. Try using a polypill like [clipboard-polyfill](https://github.com/lgarron/clipboard-polyfill)!

Comment: Did you do some research? You can find the answer to this online easily.